# Hadoop new method in older versions

Tags: hadoop

There is a method in a new version of HADOOP.
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#concat%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path[]%29

This method is not available in Hadoop 1.0.4
Can i do something to use it?

new in hadoop and java

Answer (score 0):

Yes concat function is not availalbe in HDFS 1.0.4 as shows in the folloing HDFS doc:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html

If this function is not available in HDFS 1.0.4 then you just can't have it unless you would need to write some extra libraries to support it by yourself. I would suggest looking [this thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-222) to see how the discussion went on to support this feature and where the new code exist to see the changes if you wish to add some functionality by yourself.

Comment: Do you know how can i have 4 jobs and after to have another job in chain with th other four? i mean job1,job2,job3,job4 and the whole output input in job 5?